# Jquery datepicker return the day before

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Im using jquery to do a date filter and when im sending the date to the server im sending a different date from what i have in the model. lets say i choose from 27 Oct ,2014 to 27 Oct ,2014.

```
var fromDate = new Date($scope.date.from); //Mon Oct 27 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200
var toDate = new Date($scope.date.to); // Mon Oct 27 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200
```

and the data that send to the server is:

```
2014-10-26T22:00:00.000Z
2014-10-26T22:00:00.000Z
```

this is a day before. why this is happening?

Comment: are you converting it to UTC date format before sending it to server?

Comment: No. This is the only code i have. what i need to add?

Comment: Why this is happening because the date you send to the server is a UTC Date. Because your local time is GMT+0200 it subtracts 2 hours from 0:00. If you don't want UTC try to convert the Date to a string before you send it to the server.

Comment: When i do this i get: Mon Oct 27 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200 and this is not valid for the date filter i need pattern like i send before 2014-10-26T22:00:00.000Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to make this work is this:

```
var DateFrom = new Date(Date.UTC(fromDate.getFullYear(),fromDate.getMonth(),fromDate.getDate(),0,0,0,0));

      var DateTo = new Date(Date.UTC(toDate.getFullYear(),toDate.getMonth(),toDate.getDate(),23,59,59,0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following

```
var fromDate = new Date($scope.date.from).toUTCString();
```

There was issue with the timezone difference.

Comment: When i do this i get: Sun, 26 Oct 2014 22:00:00 GMT still dont work

Comment: @anguLaravel , you will be getting UTC Time. Convert it to your TimeZone with server code..

Comment: You are also sending 2014-10-26T22:00:00, which is 26th Oct, 2014, 22.00

Comment: No. see what i wrote in the question im sending Mon Oct 27 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0200

Comment: @A.V i need to know if it is the only way. because i dont have control on the server and i will need to tell this to the man that response on the server.